# Strapi on MongoDB: Is there a content type for unstructured data?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, strapi

Exploring Strapi on Mongo, but it seems like that it doesn't ship with a content type that makes "full use" of Mongo's "unstructured" rows/documents, i.e. name:value pairs (or JSON documents, really) of which we do NOT know the field names in advance.

AFAIS, Strapi forces you, at least using the basic content types, to structure your MongoDB collections "as if" they were SQL tables: You need to manually define all fields and their data types in advance, losing much of the MongoDB power underneath.

What I am looking for is a Strapi content type that simply accepts arbitrary name:value pairs (or, by extension, arbitrary JSON documents), the way MongoDB was designed, save for perhaps one or two uniqueness fields that must be present in all rows, which would allow me to distinguish rows (similar how Mongo internally uses _id).

I know there is a JSON field type in the Content Type Builder but that's little more than just a string field, by what it seems. Am I wrong? Using the JSON field type, you seem to get no "deep indexing" of fields present inside the JSON, nor do you get any other benefit of the MongoDB native name:value (or JSON document) model.

Being new to Strapi, can such a content type be written, as a plugin, for example?

If yes, why hasn't it been written yet, given that Strapi is already in version 3? I can't be the first to want to use the native JSON storage power of MongoDB underneath my Strapi, can I?

Here's an example of the "rows" of data that I have and wish to store. Notice that the only common field is uniqueid:

```
[
{ uniqueid: "239847293472987200", email: "joe@example.com", name: "Joe Shmoe"},
{ uniqueid: "983342868223482682", phone: "408-555-1212", eyecolor: "brown"}
{ uniqueid: "983342868223482682", email: "jane@example.com", birthdate: "29/02/2020"}
]
```

I want Strapi to store the data exactly like that in Mongo. I do not want to turn everything except uniqueid into a JSON string and then do a lot of JSON string parsing and management. I want Mongo to be able to do that, even while using Strapi on top of it.

Possible? Has it been done and I just didn't find it?

Comment: Update: Looks like a common feature request but as of January 28, 2020, no contributor has started to work on it: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/483 and https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/c/10-custom-fields

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in assuming that the JSON attribute type is just a glorified string. In fact, with MongoDB, it saves the JSON as genuine part of the JSON document that is the entire "row", so I do get some MongoDB powers over the innards of my JSON data, which should get the ball rolling for me:

Example of how `{"hello": "world"}` assigned to the JSON field `data` ends up in Mongo:

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e6244d90282a590106da9a8"), "data" : { "hello" : "world" }, "uid" : "234242412412412330000", "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-03-06T12:40:57.505Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-03-06T12:40:57.516Z"), "__v" : 0, "id" : ObjectId("5e6244d90282a590106da9a8") }`